# DYLD, Symbol not found: _MTLTextureDescriptorClass

Tags: ios, crash-reports

We were unable to review your app as it crashed on launch. We have attached detailed crash logs to help troubleshoot this issue.

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Description: DYLD, Symbol not found: _MTLTextureDescriptorClass | Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/F631A4AC-ECF3-45E1-AF3F-509CDA7CFF33/wordbrain.app/wordbrain | Expected in: flat namespace | in /var/containers/Bundle/Application/F631A4AC-ECF3-45E1-AF3F-509CDA7CFF33/wordbrain.app/wordbrain
Triggered by Thread:  0
```